# TypeScripe ERROR : Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

after create a new project,and run the serve,then shows me following error.
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

node: 12.14
npm: 6.13

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-tour-of-heroes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.6.3"
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67C2W.png)

Comment: Please see here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35021

Comment: This seems to be an issue without proper solution, following links doesnt seem to help. Hope someone posts a valid answer/ solution. I'd be happy to upvote if working. Since iam facing the same issue with a new project

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can try remove your node_modules and package-lock.json and then try to npm i -f. If you have an error about tsc, i think you should using yarn to install. Because there is some problems in tsc module in npm. Check it out !

Comment: tried this methods from another thread. Doesnt seem to work. it seems outdated.

Comment: I tried but it did not work .Maybe something wrong in tsc's version